# tcpdump with multiple dst IP addresses?

Tags: tcpdump

Can I specify more than 1 `dst` ip address for `tcpdump`?
If not, how shall I filter the information nicely if I only want the traffic for two specific destinations?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you could have a filter with multiple "dst host XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" clauses connected by "or", such as "dst host 192.9.200.1 or dst host 192.9.200.2".

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can add multiple source or destination ip addresses for tcpdump as a filter to your capture.
Use "dst host XXXXXX or dst host XXXXX or dst host XXXX" as a filter after your tcpdump command.

you can find several other filters with example on:
http://rationallyparanoid.com/articles/tcpdump.html

Comment: It's like, a repeated answer, isn't it :/ ?

Comment: May look like repeated but i tried to explain in my own words. Also I gave a link which is more helpful than any written answers.
#peace

Comment: Dead link as of 16 March 2021

Comment: Archive link: https://web.archive.org/web/20190213191324/https://www.rationallyparanoid.com/articles/tcpdump.html